# rename pdf cups files

Tags: bash, cups, post-processing

I have a postprocessing script for a cups-pdf printer, thats add me a headmarker ect.
I Read out a Number in the PDf and want that the pdf has the number. But its dont work.

i tried severall scripts , try do cat in variable and rename then, but it dont work.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
PID=$(pdfgrep -h 'ID' "$file" |  cut -d "/" -f2 | awk 'NR>=1'| sed 's/^[\t]*//')
Pages=$(pdftk "$file" dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//')
if [ "$Pages" == "1" ]
then
pdftk "$file" background /home/PDF/H.pdf output "${file%.pdf}_${PID}.pdf"
rm "$file"
```

How can i rename the filename with the PID Value?

Comment: "It dont work" is insufficient as a problem description. Please be specific. What were you expecting? What happens instead? The more details, the better.

Comment: @ruud Helderheim when i set mv $file $PID.pdf it dont rename the file. it has always the job name. When i try the rename script from the wiki: #!/bin/bash

FILENAME=`basename $1`
DIRNAME=`dirname $1`
DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"`

mv $1 $DIRNAME"/"$DATE".pdf"
  then i have files with the date. but i want that after the process and the with the value name from pid.

Comment: change shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` and look at the output and verify that all parameters have the expected value.

Comment: @FredrikPihl where i can find the output? when i log in the cups pdf log , i see the postproccesing script startet and end but no more output.

Comment: ok i find out with the log. and see where my failure was.i have a second question can i save a variable i a other ? value1=... save to value2?

Comment: you mean `value1=$value2` then yes. No space around `=` and perhaps use `"$2"` quotes around the variable.